# How to get url from dropbox using flysystem?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dropbox, dropbox-api, flysystem

Hello i has upload my file using laravel5, https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Dropbox integrate to dropbox and has succeed, and then i want to get the url for my imgsrc="" on the frontend, How i can get thats url?

```
dd(Flysystem::get('avatars/kenshin.jpg'));
```

[image]

Where is the url for imgsrc?

Comment: I don't know anything about Flysystem/Laravel, but it looks like it uses the Dropbox PHP SDK, so you probably could use `createShareableLink` or `createTemporaryDirectLink` as listed here: https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Dropbox/blob/master/src/DropboxManager.php Dropbox docs here: https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.Client.html#_createShareableLink https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.Client.html#_createTemporaryDirectLink

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already created a service provider for custom filesystem.

If you don't know how to do that the doc is [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem#custom-filesystems)

```
Route::get('/dropbox',function()
{
  $filename = '/text1.txt';
  $adapter = \Storage::disk('dropbox')->getAdapter();
  $client = $adapter->getClient();
  $link = $client->createTemporaryDirectLink($filename);
  return <<<EOT
    <a href="{$link[0]}">Link</a>
  EOT;
});
```

PLEASE NOTE THAT you have to prefix a "\" slash on the filename or else it will thrown an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I save a shared link while saving a new resource. Like so

```
$path = Storage::disk('dropbox')->putFile('/images', storage_path('images/' . $imageName));

$adapter = \Storage::disk('dropbox')->getDriver()->getAdapter();

$client = $adapter->getClient();

$link = $client->createSharedLinkWithSettings($path);

$newsdigest = NewsDigest::create($request->all('title','type','source', 'article') + [

    'reading_attachment' => $link['url']

]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another route for a method in your controller and pass the file name that you want to access from dropbox with the route.
Use getFile() method in your controller and pass the filename to the variable.

```
public function getFile($file_name)
{
    $client = new Client('dropbox.token','dropbox.appName');
    $this->filesystem = new Filesystem(new Dropbox($client, '/path'));

    try{
        $file = $this->filesystem->read($file_name);
    }catch (\Dropbox\Exception $e){
        return Response::json("{'message' => 'File not found'}", 404);
    }

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);

    return $response;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to upload your file in Dropbox and even get share files link in your PHP or Laravel or any PHP framework is by using this package

```
composer require kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk
```

This is how to use it, an example I made using Laravel:

[image: (An illustrative image)]

Comment: Please don’t place screenshots of code inline. That makes it difficult for readers to copy and paste the solution. Can you edit your answer to include the code in the markdown?